# Сетка bootstrap в Wordpress съезжает

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap, grid

Вот код страницы вывода новости, но почему-то в сетке съезжает блоки

```
<!-- Start the Loop. -->
<style>
    .archive .post_content .post_content {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<div class="row">
<?php
global $post;
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<!--Start post-->
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
            <div class="post thumbnail">
              <?php $format = get_post_format( $post->ID );
              ?>
              <?php $Video_embed = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_url', true);
              if ($format == 'video')  {
               echo $Video_embed;
               } elseif ($format == 'gallery')  {
                $galleries_images = get_post_galleries_images( $post ); ?>
              <?php if ( $galleries_images )  {  ?>
               <div class="flexslider">
                 <ul class="slides">
                  <?php
                   $length=sizeof($galleries_images);
                    for( $i=0;$i<$length ;$i++) {
                     $length_g=sizeof($galleries_images[$i]);
                    //$image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
                 for( $j=0;$j<$length_g ;$j++) {
                                ?>
                                 <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url($galleries_images[$i][$j]); ?>" /></a></li>
                                 <?php } }?>
                                 </ul>
                                    </div>
             <?php }
            } elseif ($format == 'image') { ?>
            <div class="post_thumbnil"  format="<? echo $format;?>">
            <?php if ((function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())) {  ?>
                <a href="<?php get_permalink() ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('post_thumbnail_loop'); ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php }  elseif ($format == 'quote')  { ?>
            <div class="post_thumbnil" format="<? echo $format;?>">
            <?php if ((function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())) { ?>
             <a href="<?php get_permalink() ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('post_thumbnail_loop'); ?></a>
             <?php } ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="image_link2 quote"></div></a>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class=" ">
                <div class="">
                <div class="post_thumbnil "  format="<? echo $format;?>">
                    <ul class="post_meta">
                        <!--li class="post_comment"><?php comments_popup_link( NO_CMNT, ONE_CMNT, '% '.CMNT); ?></li-->
                        <li class="posted_on"><span></span><?php echo get_the_time('d M Y') ?></li>
                        <!--li class="posted_by"><span></span><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></li-->
                        <!--li class="posted_in"><span></span><?php the_category(', '); ?></li-->
                    </ul>
                    <?php if ((function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php get_permalink() ?>" class=''> <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><span class="image_link2"></span></a>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Перейти на страницу <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title();  ?></a> </h5>
                </div>
                <?php  $post = get_post( get_the_ID(), ARRAY_A);
                //echo '<div class="post_content">'.$post['post_content'].'</div>'; ?>
                <!--a class="read_more" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo 'Читать далее'; ?><span></span></a-->
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile;
else: ?>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <p>
          <?php _e('sorry no post matched your criteria!', 'novellite'); ?>
        </p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
              <!--End post-->
```

Как это убрать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используете Bootstrap 3, судя по всему. Проблема, в разной высоте колонок.
Самое лучшее, что можно сделать — использовать Bootstrap 4, так как там flex, а не float и такой проблемы не будет.

Если этот вариант не подходит, то нужно задать фиксированную высоту колонкам или, в вашем случае, тексту с названием записи.